# multiple fine-uploader complete callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, fine-uploader

I have a upload page, which has two fineuploader container, and 1 manual trigger upload button. as shown in this image

[image: layout design]
Here is the upload button click event code:

```
$('#trigger-upload-namecard').click(function(){
    $('#upload-csv-file').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
    $('#upload-jpg-files').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
});
```

How I can fire a callback to do something, eg. console.log("all of them uploaded"), as soon as both the two fineUploader has complete the upload.
I know fineUploader has a option [callbacks.onAllComplete](https://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html#allComplete), but it seem to work by each fineUploader individually.

Answer (score 0):

im unsure if this will work but you can try jQuerys whena nd then.

```
$('#trigger-upload-namecard').click(function(){
    $.when(
       $('#upload-csv-file').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles'),
       $('#upload-jpg-files').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles')
    ).then(
       alert('All done!')
   );
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: it does not work as intend, the 2 'uploadStoredFiles' call are non-blocking. It display alert 'All done!' as soon as I click button.